# PHP: Display a 2D-array as table with modal form?

Tags: php, css, arrays, html-table, http-post

I'm still new at `PHP` and keep struggling to `print` a 2D-array called `$result`.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [Nickname] => Jimmy [Image] => img/player01.png ) 
        [1] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [Nickname] => Mark [Image] => img/player02.jpg ) 
        [2] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [Nickname] => Bryan [Image] => img/player03.jpg ) 
        [3] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [Nickname] => James [Image] => img/player04.png ) 
        [4] => Array ( [ID] => 5 [Nickname] => Andre [Image] => img/player05.jpg ) )
```

I would like to show the 2D-array as:

1. Table: (The whole array showing as rows and columns).
2. Modal form: (A selected row as popup window on top of the table page).

Following snippet displays the table quite well. However, I ask myself:

1. How to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` to pass `playerid` to the `function`?
2. Is it possible to make a `modal form` (popup window) in `PHP`?

`Javascript` solutions I've found already. I'm looking for a `PHP`, or only `HTML`/`CSS` solution. Any advise would be more than welcome.

```
<table>
<?php foreach($result as $row): ?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="?playerid=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Link to individual Player</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <img src="<?php echo $row['Image']; ?>" alt="image" height="50px" width="50px">
  </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php
  if (isset($_GET['playerid'])) {
    playerid($_GET['playerid']);
  }

  function playerid($res) {
    echo $res;
  }
?>
```

Comment: If it works, and if the result makes it through the W3C validator, then you're doing it right. But questions like that belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The other questions can be asked here, but it would be better if you ask only one question per question.

Comment: Questions 1 and 2 are moved to code review. I'm just new on the site, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3. You can use `$_POST` with posted data, that is, if the form from which the data is sent has `method="post"` instead of the default `method="get"`.
4. You cannot make the page do anything with PHP after it has already been sent to the client (the browser, that is). PHP happens on the server. Client side processing requires JavaScript.
   So this depends on what you want to achieve, i.e. what you want the popup to pop up as a result of. Maybe you can make it work with CSS `:hover`, but it depends on the situation.

Comment: @MarkB If you have a solution now, you can post an answer yourself and accept it, so this question no longer shows up in the list of unanswered ones.

Comment: I don't really have a solution yet. PHP can't do it as I understand, CSS maybe. Anyway, I'm looking into a javascript HTML DOM solution.